# convert datepicker date to mysql date

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, date, datepicker

I am using datepicker with from and to dates.

When posting these dates in PHP the date format is mm/dd/yyyy.

I need to convert this to MySQL format yyyy-mm-dd

Can it be done like this?

```
$from = $_GET['from'];
$phpdate = strtotime( $from );
$from_date = date( 'Y-m-d', $phpdate );
```

I tried this but it doesn't work.

Comment: ;can you print $from_data, $phpdate, $from. its working on mine

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should use **[DateTime::createFromFormat](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php)**

Ex:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y','02/10/2015');
echo $date->format("Y-m-d");
// 2015-02-10
```

So in your case

```
$from = $_GET['from'];
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y',$from);
$from_date = $date->format("Y-m-d");
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this [Check maual here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php)

```
$from = $_GET['from'];
$phpdate=$from;
$fromdate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($phpdate));
```

Comment: I don't see a functional change according to the questioned code?

Answer (score 1):

**Try this it will work :**

```
$from = $_GET['from'];
$phpdate=$from;
$fromdate = date("Y-m-d",strtotime($phpdate));
```

Comment: I don't see a functional change according to the questioned code?

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
$from = $_GET['from'];
$date_array=explode("/",$from);
$new_date_array=array($date_array[2], $date_array[0], $date_array[1]);
echo $new_date=implode("/",$new_date_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
date("Y-m-d", strtotime($_GET['<name>']));
```