# Converting jQuery datepicker into MysQl Date format

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, date, datepicker

**I have datepicker**

```
<input class='form-control formBlock datepick' name='period_startdate' value='' type='text' placeholder="Enter First Work Date..." required>
```

**datepicker script**

```
<script>
$('.datepick').each(function(){
    $(this).datepicker();
});
</script>
```

**sql statement**

```
    [other variables...]

    //datepicker variable
    $period_startdate=$_POST['period_startdate'];

    $insertpayperiod= $db->prepare("INSERT INTO payroll (pay_name,pay_group,payday,gross_paycheck,payrate,annual_gross_income,pay_slip_type,pay_rate_unit,total_weekly_hours,total_yearly_hours,created_byid) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
    $insertpayperiod->bind_param("siiiiissiii",$pay_name,$paygroup,$payday,$gross_paycheck,$payrate,$annual_gross_income,$paysliptype,$payrateunit,$total_weekly_hours,$total_yearly_hours,$createdbyid);
```

**MysQl Date format**

```
0000-00-00
```

How can I convert this to mysql date and make an insert? I have taken notes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28713420/convert-datepicker-date-to-mysql-date). I did read the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php). But while I somehow understand the concept I cant wrap my head around doing it dynamically `:-/`

Comment: what mysql date format do you want? What display format do you want?

Comment: When constructing the SQL INSERT, you can supply the string returned by the field, and convert it to a date using the STR_TO_DATE function. Depending on the format returned, this function allows you to specify how to transform it. If you show the SQL statement and the date format you receive in your question above, I can then show you how to format the string

Comment: @charlietfl: Mysql Date 0000-00-00

Comment: @SloanThrasher: I updated my question

Comment: @SloanThrasher: I did find something useful here http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-str_to_date-function.php

Comment: I solved the problem with a solution different from the duplicate page. What they suggested there did not work for me... I solved it with actually formating the datepicker directly with jQuery.